# sigma notation of Taylor series of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I am having trouble finding the sigma notation for the taylor series of $f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ with the bound $b = 1$. I believe I found a solution but I would like to find one that doesn't involve a double factorial.
This is the solution I found:
$$T_n(x) =\sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^k\frac{(2k-1)!!}{k!\cdot2^k}(x-1)^k$$

Comment: Shouldn't the $(2n-1)!!$ really be $(2k-1)!!$?

Comment: You can express the double factorial as $n!!=\begin{cases}2^{n/2}\cdot(n/2)!,&n\ \text{even}\\
\frac{(n+1)!}{2^{(n+1)/2}\cdot ((n+1)/2)!},&n\ \text{odd}\end{cases}$ and then split the sum up or use an indicator function for odds and evens (e.g. $\frac{(-1)^n+1}{2}$).

Comment: @Mnifldz you're right that was a typo.

Comment: @Jam since $(2k-1)$ is always odd, could I just use the odd definition?

Comment: @gommb Absolutely. Just stick $(2k-1)$ into the equation above for $n\ \text{odd}$ and you get the same series. You should get $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2k)!}{\left(k!\right)^{2}\cdot2^{2k}}(1-x)^{k}$ if you simplify. Note that the series is only convergent for $|1-x|<1$

Comment: What do you have against the double factorial ? Whatever notation you use, the coefficients will be the same.

Comment: By the way, what is $(-1)!!$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the simplest notation could be
$$T_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{-\frac{1}{2}}{k}(x-1)^k$$

Answer (score 0):

Given the well-known $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x}}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{2k}{k} x^k,$$
note that $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4(1-x)/4}}$$ and perform the change of variable $x\mapsto (1-x)/4$ to obtain $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{2k}{k} \left(\frac{1-x}{4}\right)^k=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\binom{2k}{k}}{(-4)^k} (x-1)^k.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{(2k-1)!!}{2^k}=\frac{\Gamma\left(k-\frac12\right)}{\sqrt\pi}.$$

You can also absorb the sign with

$$(-1)^k\frac{(2k-1)!!}{2^k}=\frac{\sqrt\pi}{\Gamma(\frac12-k)}.$$

Comment: Off-by-one errors not excluded...